# Angular: $observe an element's text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I already know that you can use `attr.$observe` within a directive to watch the attributes if they change.

Is there an equivalent to watch the text within an element?

```
<div my-directive ng-bind="myText || 'Watch me!!!'">Watch me!!!</div>
```

In the above example, I'd want to watch the text "Watch me!!!".  I'd much prefer to do this rather than `$watch` what is being bound to the directive because of scoping issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching the DOM for changes is **EXPENSIVE**, also there is no built in way within Angular to do so. Watching the scope for changes is the correct way to do this.

If you are having issues with scoping then perhaps, with more I formation,that is something we could help with as well.

Comment: Nope, was just me being lazy.  In retrospect you're completely right, and I've refactored such that watching the scope is easier.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to watch DOM changes, here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kihu/t7zr71ma/5/

The trick is to pass a function returning anything you want to watch, e.g.:

```
  scope.$watch(function () {
                return element.text();
            }, handleChange)
```

But I think @Enzey is right, you should avoid watching the DOM, instead you should bind data from angular scope and watch it.